# How to use the "|" given symbol for a mixed model in julia expression

Tags: julia

I want to programmatically iterate over some dependent variables and create some formulas using the MixedModels package, so things like:

```
form = @formula(y ~ 1 + x1 + x2 + (1 + x1 + x2 | stuff))
```

Ideally I would have an array of symbols for dependent variables and iterate over them and create formulas of different kinds:

```
depvars = [:height, :weight]

for var in depvars
    my_formula = @formula(var ~ otherstuff + (1 + otherstuff | thing))
    lm_out = fit!(lmm(my_formula, data))
end
```

where `otherstuff` and `thing` would change. If I didn't have a mixed model then I would probably do something like:

```
depvars = [:height, :weight]
f1 = Expr(:call, :+, [:x1, :x2])
f2 = Expr(:call, :+, [:x3, :x4])

for var in depvars
    my_formula1 = Formula(var, f1)
    my_formula2 = Formula(var, f2)
    lm_out = lm(my_formula1, data)
    # and so on...
end
```

but I'm not sure if I can express the portion `(1 + x1 + x2 | stuff)` in an expression.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `@formula` directly using `DataFrames.Formula` and interpolation in quoted expressions:

```
using MixedModels, DataFrames

depvars = [:height, :weight]
things = [:thing1, :thing2]
otherstuffs = [:other1, :other2]

for thing in things, otherstuff in otherstuffs
    for var in depvars
        my_formula = Formula(var, :( $otherstuff + (1 +$otherstuff | $thing)))
        @show my_formula
    end
end
```

Gives:

```
my_formula = Formula: height ~ other1 + ((1 + other1) | thing1)
my_formula = Formula: weight ~ other1 + ((1 + other1) | thing1)
my_formula = Formula: height ~ other2 + ((1 + other2) | thing1)
my_formula = Formula: weight ~ other2 + ((1 + other2) | thing1)
my_formula = Formula: height ~ other1 + ((1 + other1) | thing2)
my_formula = Formula: weight ~ other1 + ((1 + other1) | thing2)
my_formula = Formula: height ~ other2 + ((1 + other2) | thing2)
my_formula = Formula: weight ~ other2 + ((1 + other2) | thing2)
```